# Oracle: Remotely import using Impdp with DB link

Tags: oracle, plsql, impdp, ora-12170

I'm trying to import a schema using data pump. Here's my problem: I can only access the [impdp](/questions/tagged/impdp) utility on the source DB server, but it's version 11.1, and the target DB version is 11.2, so if I run the import, I got an error:

```
UDI-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 11.01.00.06.00
```

I want to work around this by using my laptop, installed with the Oracle express version 11.2, same version as the target DB, by using this command:

```
impdp username/password@targetDB directory=data_pump_dir network_link=sourceDB schemas=EMP
```

In this command, **`targetDB`** is a public db link created on my local oracle, and the same record has been added to `tnsnames.ora`; **`sourceDB`** is a public db link created in the target DB, pointing to the source DB.

But I got this error:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39200: Link name "sourceDB" is invalid.
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

The source DB version is:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production PL/SQL Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
CORE 11.1.0.6.0 Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
```

The target DB version is:

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

My local DB version is:

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production              
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production                                           
CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production                                                         
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production                          
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

So what did I do wrong?

Is there a way to import from the source to target?

Comment: Did you put `sourceDB` in double-quotes on the command line? The error `Link name "sourceDB"` suggests you did, but I don't know if you've changed the names for posting. The name will be case sensitive though, so it you created the DB link unquoted then it should be either unquoted on the command line, and/or all in upper-case. Also, did you see if the [`version` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL944) allowed it to work without the link? (See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL110) too).

Comment: Thank you @AlexPoole, from the document it says two databases "differ by no more than one version". So if I import a 11.1 DB to a 11.2 DB it should not be a problem, but I got the UDI-00018 error. I tried to add double quotes to the db link, no luck. The version parameter also doesnot work for me, I tried to use version=11.1, 11.01, 10.1, etc.

Comment: Yes, not sure if `version` works when you're using a link, I've used it on export. If you log in as `username/password@targetdb` and `select link_name from all_db_links`, is it shown all in uppercase, and does it exactly match your `network_link` value? (The link going the other way isn't relevant). I think you should be able to do this from the 11.1 server, maybe with `version`; not sure the laptop step is needed.

Comment: Yes I used upper case, but I replaced it when posting here.

Comment: But is it uppercase in `all_db_links` (assuming it is public and you can see it), or was it created as quoted mixed case? I'm struggling to see what else might be wrong. Showing the exact command you used for the link creation (or at least what's in `all_db_links`) and for the import *may* help; wouldn't be the first time changing something when posting hid the actual problem...

Comment: The db link is public, the name is all uppercase, no quotes. Then I tried uppercase, lowercase, with and without quotes. I know changing is not good but I'm not allowed to post the original here, sorry :(

Comment: understand that, but makes life harder. If the link is in the correct DB, pointing the right way, and named as you think, then this ought to work. Which doesn't help you much...

Comment: Since you get **`ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred`** Its also possible that its impossible to access the database's port. Have you tried a simple query accessing this db-link??

Answer (score 0):

### It looks like you cannot access your local database remotely:

In order to avoid

> `ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred`
>   Is to make sure that you are able to connect to the remote database.

I advise you start making sure it works with a simple query accessing the db-link:

```
SQL> select * from dual@sourceDB;
```

### Another solution

Another solution to your problem is to specify the target version of the export file at the time you export it, e.g. with:

```
version=11.1
```